# Jquery How to writing firebase realtime with submit form

Tags: jquery, firebase, forms, firebase-realtime-database, form-submit

I try to writing firebase realtime DB with form

But not working, Form can submitted but data don't writing to DB

```
<script type="module">

   const fname = $(".fname");
   const lname = $(".lname");


   function insertDB() {

       set(ref(db, "/docHR/empProfiles/"), {

           fname:   fname.val(),
           lname:   lname.val(),

       })
   }

</script>
```

> Solution 1  // not working

```
<form onSubmit="insertDB()">
  <input type="text" class="fname">
  <input type="text" class="lname">
<button type="submit" class="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

> Solution 2  // not working

```
btnSubmit.click(function() {
    insertDB();
});
```

I try to change button type from submit to button, it's working but form is not submitted.

Comment: I think you need to use [`preventDefault();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Comment: thank you but page is not refresh, How refresh page also

Comment: After insert, `window.location.reload();`

Comment: That sounds like an answer @SimoneRossaini!  

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen seems like yes :D but this question is super duplicate no?